# Error 'Mov wrong parameters'

Tags: assembly, emulation, low-level, emu8086

I'm starting to learn Assembly (ASM x86). I'm using the emulator emu8086. I've written the following instruction:

```
mov eax,3
```

When I'm trying to emulate the instruction, emu8086 writes: `wrong parameters MOV eax,3. probably it's an undefined var: eax`

In addition, when I replaced `eax` with `ax`, `ah` or `al` - It worked just fine.

Why is it like that? What should I do in order to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

emu8086 emulates the original 8086. It's a 16 bit processor, so there are no 32 bit registers (eax, ebx, etc.)

For a bit more information on the register layout, check out the [Wikipedia page on the Intel 8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Registers_and_instructions).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any other emulator which is suitable to usage of 32 bit registers too?

Comment: @Programmer try the NASM assembler

Comment: I don't know of any that are as interactive as emu8086. However, you can use an emulator like [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) and use an assembler like [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) to get 32 bit (and 64 bit) emulation.

Comment: @Programmer Note: things get a lot more complicated when you are attempting to emulate 32 bits. You have to actually go through the process of switching the (emulated) CPU into 32 bit mode, which is a whole topic in itself. If you want 32 bit assembly, you may be best off just writing native assembly programs for whatever OS you are on.

Answer (score 0):

```
db 66h
mov ax, 3
db 0, 0
```

Should emulate `mov eax, 3` (in 16-bit code) in an assembler that doesn't support it. Easier to use an assembler that does...

Comment: This of course won't run on an 8086 or an 8088 processor, and will throw an unknown opcode in emu8086.